# Search in patterns list

Tags: user-agent, browser-detection

I have list of objects like this:

```
    {
       "pattern": "Mozilla/5.0 (*Mac OS X 10?4*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.*Safari/*",
       "name": "Macintosh",
       "brand": "Apple"
    }
    {
        "pattern": "Mozilla/5.0 (*Windows NT 5.1*rv:46.0*) Gecko/*/",
        "name": "Windows",
        "brand": "Microsoft"
  }
```

or like this (the same, but in regular expression notation):

```
{
    "pattern": "mozilla/5\.0 \(.*linux.*android.4\.4.*gxt_dongle_3188 build/.*\) applewebkit/.* \(khtml, like gecko\) version/.* chrome/.*safari/.* bdbrowserhd_i18n/1\.(\d).*",
     "name": "Macintosh",
     "brand": "Apple"
}
```

This is dictionary of browser user agents with 7000 items. I have user agent string, for example:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"

And I need to find name and brand as fast as possible. Now I split dictionary by chunks (100 patterns) and glue to one big regexp. After this I try to match user agent of this big regexp. If matched - I walk all items of this chunk.

Would you recommend some DB engine which can help me with this? Or simply algorithm which can help me do it faster?